# Simulate iOS's "reduce white point" feature on OS X El Capitan

Tags: display, macos

I've become fond of iOS's "[reduce white point](https://www.imobie.com/support/how-to-reduce-white-point-in-ios-10.htm)" accessibility feature to reduce the intensity of bright colors, which makes the screen much easier to use in the dark -- nicer, in my opinion, than simply turning down the brightness.

On OS X El Capitan version 10.11, is there a way to simulate this feature using native OS X tools, or ones available on the internet? I couldn't find anything.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you take a photo of with and without

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I lower the minimum display brightness? How?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/54821/can-i-lower-the-minimum-display-brightness-how)

Comment: @ankiiiiiii, what the OP wants is not a duplicate. I have that same necessity for some monitors, which distort whitepoint, and reducing brightness does not help it. But reducing the whitepoint using Gamma Control (as posted below) fix it. So this is a different question and I know well what the OP wants because I suffer from the same problem.

Comment: @Prado OP hasn't been online lately, but it would be better to reject all the apps in that question after trying them once at least. the answer with 19 upvotes has some indicators about good apps

Comment: @ankiiiiiii, yes, the best solution is to find any native way for doing that using internal MacOS commands, and not some external application. I agree with you. Thank you, I am reading the 19 upvotes answer.!

Answer (score 4):

This is a solution that work nicely, but it is not free.

Gamma Control - is a professional app to control the brightness of color on your mac. Really useful to correct color & black on any projector, that's why I paid for it at first ~25$.

Get it in the [App Store](https://apps.apple.com/ca/app/contr%C3%B4le-gamma-6/id1250521285?l=fr&mt=12)

The put these setting on:

1- Max brightness on you mac

2- In Gamma Control put the **White** Point Luminance as you like (between 0.3 and 0.6 I enjoy)

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what the OP needs/want to do. The author of this app has a Github account with several source code he used to create it. I don't know if you a are a user or a developer, but the information about how he does that is there. On the authors home page there is link to his Github account.

Answer (score -1):

If the goal is to have a

> feature to reduce the intensity of bright colors, which makes the screen much easier to use in the dark

Then this is quite a stupid way to go about:

> [image]

As usual the tools and settings provided by Apple do not do anything useful:

> **Apple’s color adjustments don’t do much**
>
> On a screen this bright and effective at delivering bright light to the eye, the mild “Night Shift” settings Apple provides just don’t have much impact.
>   Night Shift’s default setting is not capable of dialing things back to the level of the old phones with Night Shift turned off.
>   Compared to previous phones, with the screen the same brightness (luminance), your eyes will see twice as many melanopic-weighted photons as you would on an iPhone 6 (20% from the spectrum, and nearly double from the geometry and directionality).
>   Let’s be clear: this screen is now well beyond the range of early iPads to delay sleep. It’s not a “little” screen anymore, and it’s very good at making light that your non-visual photoreceptors will see.
>   <sub>[Measuring the brightest iPhone ever: iPhone X](https://justgetflux.com/news/2018/02/16/OLED.html)</sub>

The right tool for this kind of job is [f.lux.](https://justgetflux.com/)

> Ever notice how people texting at night have that eerie blue glow?
>
> Or wake up ready to write down the Next Great Idea, and get blinded by your computer screen?
>
> During the day, computer screens look good—they're designed to look like the sun. But, at 9PM, 10PM, or 3AM, you probably shouldn't be looking at the sun.
>
> f.lux fixes this: it makes the color of your computer's display adapt to the time of day, warm at night and like sunlight during the day.
>
> It's even possible that you're staying up too late because of your computer. You could use f.lux because it makes you sleep better, or you could just use it just because it makes your computer look better.
>
> f.lux makes your computer screen look like the room you're in, all the time. When the sun sets, it makes your computer look like your indoor lights. In the morning, it makes things look like sunlight again.
>
> Tell f.lux what kind of lighting you have, and where you live. Then forget about it. f.lux will do the rest, automatically.

At least there used to be other tools available ([Nocturne](https://code.google.com/archive/p/blacktree-nocturne/downloads), DarkAdapted, RedScreen or similar…) and you might also play just with display colour profiles to achieve a similar effect. That is basically  just a nuisance and requires manual intervention all the time. But the above tool called f.lux just does it all with less hassle, customisable and automatically. You might also change the preferences to suite your needs in terms of colour better. It just works.

Comment: see my comment to the other poster and let me know if I'm mistaken.

Answer (score -2):

Using the built-in calibration tool in System Preference > Displays, you can adjust the whitepoint of your monitor:

[image]

and save as many profiles as you wish:

[image]

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, but this adjusts the color temperature and seems to give different results (closer to f.lux) than the iOS accessibility feature. The "reduce whitepoint" feature appears to be more like a brightness reducer than a color-temperature changer.

Comment: If you have an iPhone, try it out and see what I mean. Settings -> Accessibility -> Reduce Whitepoint.

Comment: On second thought... it looks like the color temperature is actually changed (warmer, so -- consistent with what you're doing) on the iPhone, so it's possible I am just mistaken. The brightness however is definitely reduced as well.

Comment: This just changes the temperature, not the whitepoint level intensity, which is what the OP needs